# stripe payment gateway problem in React Redux

Tags: stripe-payments, express-checkout

**This project is working fine, and also checkout works fine but stripe does not show any payment.**

**Maybe I missed some code in checkout.js to set my stripe payment gateway ... but I could not find that.**

**this is chekcout.jsx**

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { confirmOrder, setPromoCode } from "../store/actions";
import CheckoutCartProduct from "../components/Checkout/CheckoutCartProduct";
import PromoCodeForm from "../components/Checkout/PromoCodeForm";
import PromoCodeValue from "../components/Checkout/PromoCodeValue";
import CheckoutCartTotals from "../components/Checkout/CheckoutCartTotals";
import CustomerInputs from "../components/Checkout/Forms/CustomerInputs";
import DeliveryOptions from "../components/Checkout/Forms/DeliveryOptions";
import PaymentOptions from "../components/Checkout/Forms/Payments/PaymentOptions";
import Alert from "../components/UI/Alert/Alert";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import formValidator from "../Utility/formValidation";
import { CardElement, injectStripe } from "react-stripe-elements";
import { currencyToUse } from "../Utility/currency";

class Checkout extends Component {
  state = {
    promoCode: "",
    showAlert: false,
    alertType: "",
    alertMessage: "",
    paymentMethod: "creditCard",
    shippingPrice: 300,
    usedDeliveryOption: 1,
    makeOrder: false,
    correctCardInfo: false,
    customerInfo: {
      firstName: {
        value: "",
        valid: false,
        touched: false,
        errorsMsg: "",
      },
      secondName: {
        value: "",
        valid: false,
        touched: false,
        errorsMsg: "",
      },
      email: {
        value: "",
        valid: false,
        touched: false,
        errorsMsg: "",
      },
    },
  };

  customerInfoChangeHandler = (event, identifier) => {
    // use deep cloning to be able to get the values of nested objects
    const customerInfo = { ...this.state.customerInfo };
    const customerInfoField = { ...customerInfo[identifier] };
    customerInfoField.value = event.target.value;
    const validationResults = formValidator(
      identifier,
      customerInfoField.value
    );
    customerInfoField.valid = validationResults.isValid;
    customerInfoField.errorsMsg = validationResults.errorsMsg;
    customerInfoField.touched = true;
    customerInfo[identifier] = customerInfoField;

    let makeOrder = true;
    for (let identifier in customerInfo) {
      makeOrder = customerInfo[identifier].valid && makeOrder;
    }
    this.setState({ customerInfo: customerInfo, makeOrder: makeOrder });
  };

  promoCodeChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ promoCode: event.target.value });
  };

  paymentOptionChangeHandler = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value === "creditCard") {
      this.setState({ correctCardInfo: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ correctCardInfo: true });
    }
    this.setState({ paymentMethod: event.target.value });
  };

  confirmOrderHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let order = {};
    order["cart"] = this.props.cartProductsProps;
    order["user"] = {
      firstName: this.state.customerInfo.firstName.value,
      secondName: this.state.customerInfo.secondName.value,
      email: this.state.customerInfo.email.value,
    };
    order["usedPromoCode"] = this.state.promoCode;
    order["currency"] = this.props.usedCurrencyProp;
    order["paymentMethod"] = this.state.paymentMethod;
    order["deliveryOption"] = this.state.usedDeliveryOption;

    // todo

   
    // create stripe token for payments

    
    this.props.confirmOrderProp(order);
  };

  setPromoCode = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // check promo code in state
    let getPromoCode = this.props.promoCodeProp.filter(
      (codeName) => codeName.code === this.state.promoCode
    );

    if (getPromoCode.length > 0) {
      this.props.setPromoCodeProp(getPromoCode[0]);
      this.setState({
        showAlert: true,
        alertType: "alert-success",
        alertMessage: `The promo code you entered has given you a ${getPromoCode[0].percentage}% discount on the total price.`,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        showAlert: true,
        alertType: "alert alert-danger",
        alertMessage: "The Promo code you entered does not have discounts",
      });
    }
  };

  closeAlertHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAlert: !this.state.showAlert,
      alertType: "",
      alertMessage: "",
    });
  };

  deliveryOptionChangeHandler = (event) => {
    //get used delivery option from the state
    let deliveryOption = this.props.deliveryOptions.find(
      (option) => option.id === parseInt(event.target.value)
    );
    if (deliveryOption) {
      this.setState({
        usedDeliveryOption: parseInt(event.target.value),
        shippingPrice: deliveryOption.cost,
      });
    }
  };

  creditCardHandler = (element) => {
    if (element.complete) {
      this.setState({ correctCardInfo: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    let productsPrices = [];
    let chosenPaymentMethod = null;
    let currencyKeys = currencyToUse(this.props.usedCurrencyProp);
    let currencyValue = currencyKeys.value;

    const cartProducts = this.props.cartProductsProps.map(
      (cartProduct, index) => {
        // fetch product information from source based on id
        let productFromStore = this.props.productsProps.find(
          (product) => product.id === cartProduct.id
        );
        productsPrices.push({
          price:
            productFromStore.quantity > 0
              ? Math.round(productFromStore.price * currencyValue)
              : 0,
          count: cartProduct.quantity,
        });
        return (
          <CheckoutCartProduct
            key={index}
            checkoutProductName={productFromStore.name}
            checkoutProductCategory={productFromStore.category}
            checkoutProductPrice={Math.round(
              productFromStore.price * currencyValue
            )}
            checkoutProductImage={productFromStore.img}
            checkoutCartCount={cartProduct.quantity}
            checkoutCartSize={cartProduct.size}
            currency={this.props.usedCurrencyProp}
            
          />
        );
      }
    );

    let shippingPrice = this.state.shippingPrice
      ? Math.round(this.state.shippingPrice * currencyValue)
      : 0;
    let productTotals = productsPrices.reduce(
      (acc, el) => acc + el.price * el.count,
      0
    );
    let vatPercentage = this.props.vatProps > 0 ? this.props.vatProps / 100 : 0;
    let vat = productTotals > 0 ? Math.round(productTotals * vatPercentage) : 0;
    let percentageDiscount = this.props.usedPromoCodeProp
      ? this.props.usedPromoCodeProp.percentage / 100
      : 0;
    let discountAmount = productTotals * percentageDiscount;
    let shoppingTotal =
      productTotals > 0
        ? productTotals + vat + shippingPrice - discountAmount
        : 0;

    if (this.state.paymentMethod === "creditCard") {
      chosenPaymentMethod = (
        <div className={"ml-4 p-3 shop-card-field"}>
          <CardElement
            onChange={(element) => this.creditCardHandler(element)}
          />
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.state.paymentMethod === "onDelivery") {
      chosenPaymentMethod = (
        <div className={"ml-4 p-3"}>
          You will pay when the product is delivered to you.
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="container py-4">
        {this.props.cartTotalProps <= 0 ? <Redirect to="/cart" /> : null}

        {this.state.showAlert ? (
          <Alert
            alertType={this.state.alertType}
            closeAlert={this.closeAlertHandler}
          >
            {this.state.alertMessage}
          </Alert>
        ) : null}

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
            <h4 className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
              <span className="text-muted">Order Review</span>
              <span className="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">
                {this.props.cartTotalProps}
              </span>
            </h4>

            <ul className="list-group mb-3">
              {/* items in cart */}
              {cartProducts}

              {/* used promo codes */}
              {this.props.usedPromoCodeProp ? (
                <PromoCodeValue
                  currency={this.props.usedCurrencyProp}
                  usedPromoCode={this.props.usedPromoCodeProp}
                  discountAmount={discountAmount}
                />
              ) : null}

              {/* checkout totals */}
              <CheckoutCartTotals
                productTotals={productTotals}
                vat={vat}
                shippingPrice={shippingPrice}
                shoppingTotal={shoppingTotal}
                currency={this.props.usedCurrencyProp}
              />
            </ul>

            {/*promo code form */}
            <PromoCodeForm
              setPromoCode={this.setPromoCode}
              promoCodeChangeHandler={(event) =>
                this.promoCodeChangeHandler(event)
              }
              promoCode={this.state.promoCode}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-8 order-md-1 ">
            <h4 className="mb-3">Billing Information</h4>
            <form className="shop-form shop-bg-white p-3" noValidate>
              {/* customer details form fields */}
              <CustomerInputs
                customerInfo={this.state.customerInfo}
                inputChanged={(event, identifier) =>
                  this.customerInfoChangeHandler(event, identifier)
                }
              />
              {/* delivery options selection fields */}
              <h4 className="">Delivery Options</h4>
              <DeliveryOptions
                currency={this.props.usedCurrencyProp}
                deliveryOptions={this.props.deliveryOptions}
                usedDeliveryOption={this.state.usedDeliveryOption}
                deliveryOptionChanged={this.deliveryOptionChangeHandler}
              />

              <h4 className="mb-3">Payment Method</h4>
              {/* payment option selection field */}
              <PaymentOptions
                paymentMethod={this.state.paymentMethod}
                paymentOptionChanged={this.paymentOptionChangeHandler}
              />
              {/* payment section */}
              <div>{chosenPaymentMethod}</div>

              <hr className="mb-4" />
              <button
                disabled={!(this.state.makeOrder && this.state.correctCardInfo)}
                className="btn shop-btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block"
                onClick={(event) => this.confirmOrderHandler(event)}
              >
                Confirm Order
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Checkout.propTypes = {
  productsProps: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  cartProductsProps: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  cartTotalProps: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  promoCodeProp: PropTypes.array,
  usedPromoCodeProp: PropTypes.object,
  deliveryOptions: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  usedCurrencyProp: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  vatProps: PropTypes.number,
};

Checkout.defaultProps = {
  shippingPriceProp: 0,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    productsProps: state.products,
    cartProductsProps: state.cart,
    cartTotalProps: state.cartTotal,
    vatProps: state.vat,
    promoCodeProp: state.promoCode,
    usedPromoCodeProp: state.usedPromoCode,
    deliveryOptions: state.deliveryOptions,
    usedCurrencyProp: state.usedCurrency,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    confirmOrderProp: (order) => dispatch(confirmOrder(order, ownProps)),
    setPromoCodeProp: (promoCode, percentage) =>
      dispatch(setPromoCode(promoCode, percentage)),
  };
};

// inject stripe prop into the component
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(injectStripe(Checkout));
```

**this is index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store/store";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./index.css";
import {  Elements, StripeProvider  } from "react-stripe-elements";
import App from "./App";

const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      {/* StripeProvider initializes the stripe and passes in the publishable key */}
      <StripeProvider apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}>
        <Elements>

          <App />
          
        </Elements>
      </StripeProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**I also add the .env file and stripe key, this code is from Github I want to set the payment gateway by stripe but I don't understand what I need to do.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to [create a PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=node#create_payment_intent) from your server, and pass its [client_secret](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object?lang=node#payment_intent_object-client_secret) to frontend and call [stripe.confirmCardPayment](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment) so that Stripe can process this payment.

You can find the complete integration guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/card-element?client=react&lang=node).

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Brother,

To successfully complete a Stripe payment, we need to follow some steps. Here are the steps:

 1. We need to implement card elements on the checkout page.
 2. We need to create a payment method as shown below:

const { error: stripeError, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
  type: "card",
  card: elements.getElement(CardExpiryElement, CardNumberElement, CardCvcElement),
});


We need to create a PaymentIntent using the above payment method key. To achieve this, we should pass the payment method key to the backend to create the PaymentIntent.
We need to confirm the PaymentIntent with the client secret key. If third-party validation is required, we need to pass the 3D authentication key; otherwise, the normal payment confirmation method is sufficient.

if (paymentIntent.status === "requires_action") {
  // Let Stripe.js handle the rest of the payment flow.
  const { error: actionError } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret);
  if (actionError) {
    ev.complete('fail');
    setPaymentStatus('Payment actionError error');
    return;
    // The payment failed -- ask your customer for a new payment method.
  } else {
    paymentSuccessShow(true);
    setPaymentStatus('Payment succeeded');
    navigate("/orderstatus");
    ev.complete('success');
    // The payment has succeeded -- show a success message to your customer.
  }
}

These steps ensure a smooth and successful Stripe payment process. If you have any questions or need further clarification, feel free to ask.
```